Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Why did the program entry point become 'sub esp, 1C'?

Net Score: 9 (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)


Adding another section to an idb file

Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)


How to identify functions in a stripped binary on x86 32bit?

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)


Dumping firmware through mtdblock device

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


Who does construct the stack on process creation in Windows?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)


Interacting with command line programs in Hopper disassembler (Mac OS 10.9)

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


Decompiling windows photo viewer

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)


Win7 ASLR bypass

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 1)


Modifying a binary save-data file for a video game with a CRC/Checksum check

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)


How are dylib files laid out

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 3)

